# Undefined control sequence. \@begindocumenthook with incgraph package

Tags: graphics

I am getting an error that I cannot understand. Using package incgraph. I have searched Undefined control sequence. @begindocumenthook incgraph unsuccesfully. Using lualatex.
Any assistance greatly appreciated.

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\@begindocumenthook ...eWidth {\the \pdfpagewidth 
                                                  }\edef \igrOrginalPageHeig...

l.7 \begin{document}
                  %
```

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{incgraph}
\begin{document}%
\incgraph{0001.png}
\incgraph{0002.png}
\incgraph{0003.png}
\incgraph{0004.png}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Why not compile with pdflatex?